# Substitute strings by references in an Excel sheet

Tags: excel, replace, substitution

I have a large Excel sheet with lots of repetitive strings in cells, which I need to replace/substitute by a reference:

[image]

I have tried so far the Excel function `SUBSTITUTE` but not managed to make it work...
Any idea how to use it properly to achieve my requirement?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the hint of @Scott I managed to solve it but using `XLOOKUP(A1;D$1:D$3;E$1:E$3)`, which I find more clear than his proposed solution.
Thanks anyway!

Comment: Is mapping alpha characters to numbers your literal use case, or is that just an example? To map alpha to numbers you don't need a lookup table. You can use CODE([value]) - 64 to get your number mapping to upper alpha characters.

Comment: @DavidRichardson thanks; it is just an example. The real use case is free text instead of characters, being mapped to INT that later will be used as an Id when importing all data in sheets to a database

Answer (score 1):

Use VLOOKUP:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,D:E,2,FALSE)
```

[image]